# Flutter webview doesn't load big videos

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm displaying videos using a webview, but sometimes they aren't loaded.

I've tried different options but result is the same. I think it's related specifically to big videos like this:

https://ipfs.blockfrost.dev/ipfs/QmPD4hiWn9gtYwMFP35DqesJVqPBGjVPzADNG5TLe6tmwd

My code is really simple and works for other pages (even smaller videos):

```
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: "https://ipfs.blockfrost.dev/ipfs/QmWQmwZCP5Q2uXg4Ekh5Rna7ezd81cNQLbNKv8USVpTebA",
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      initialMediaPlaybackPolicy: AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.always_allow,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
      }
    );
  }
```

This is the log when I try to load this page (it's a video):

```
D/mali_winsys(17719): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/mali_winsys(17719): native_window_api_disconnect failed: -19
D/HwCustConnectivityManagerImpl(17719): isBlockNetworkRequestByNonAis, INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
D/ConnectivityManager(17719): requestNetwork and the calling app is: com.my_app.my_app
D/HwCustConnectivityManagerImpl(17719): isBlockNetworkRequestByNonAis, INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
W/libEGL  (17719): EGLNativeWindowType 0x7cc5831010 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys(17719): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
E/        (17719): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
```

And sometimes this is added to the log:

```
W/chromium(17719): [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(3541)] Received HEADERS for invalid stream 3
W/chromium(17719): [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(3541)] Received HEADERS for invalid stream 5
```

Does somebody has any idea what is the problem?